# Listen to the form submitting from component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a component, that receives `AbstractControl` as `Input`:

```
export class FormControlContainerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() control: AbstractControl;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.control.root is a form
    }
}
```

I know that I can get access to the form by using `control.root`.
How can I listen to the form submitting from this component? Is it possible?

I'm using `angular 2.3`.

Answer (score 1):

In view:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()">
```

In ctrl:

```
handleSubmit: () => {
  //  do something
}
```

Or somewhere else just subscribe to the ngSubmit:

```
  @ViewChild('loginForm') loginForm: NgForm;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm?.ngSubmit.subscribe((event: SubmitEvent) => {
      //  do somthing
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, I couldn't find anything like that in the source code , but I came up with this idea.

Where you define your form :

```
<form [formGroup]="controlGroup (submit)="controlGroup.submit.emit(controlGroup.value)">

    <input [formControl]='firstNameControl' name="firstname">
 </form>
```

in your class  ;

```
export class MyComponent {

    private controlGroup = new FormGroup({});
    // this is your root controlGroup , how ever else you've created this is alright 

   constructor(){
     this.controlGroup.submit = new EventEmitter<any>();
     // we inject an event emitter inside the root controlGroup 


     this.controlGroup.submit.subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log('form is submitted with value ',data);
     });
   }
}
```

And then you could do :

```
export class FormControlContainerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() control: AbstractControl;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.control.root.submit.subscribe((data)=>{
           console.log('form is submitted with value ',data);
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously, this looks a like a bit of a hack, but it doesn't have any harm, the preferred way would be to define a new class that extends from FormGroup and provide this submit functionality , but I was lazy to do that :D